# Fedora: Service is running, but service not found when attempting to restart

Tags: fedora, service, openldap

Fedora 8:

When I run `/sbin/service --status-all`, I see

```
slapd (pid 2285) is running...
```

as expected. When I run `/sbin/service slapd restart` I get

```
slapd: unrecognized service
```

I don't see slapd under `/etc/init.d/` either

Any ideas on how to access this service?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The service name (and the name of the init script) is `ldap`

Comment: Also, Fedora 8 hasn't been supported for some time, you should consider upgrading :)

Comment: lovely. How come service names are always different than what the actual command is?

Comment: Depends. Names of init scripts are usually dependant on the conventions used by the distribution.

Comment: Ya I'm taking over IT duties for a small company, everything is Fedora, which I'm planning on slowly changing.